# Linkify Launchpad project links

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, launchpad

I've just pasted a link to the code of a Launchpad project to an answer, and I noticed it remained as plain text. It would be nice if Launchpad shortcuts could be linkified automatically to point to the project's URL.

E.g. when I write `lp:qreator` it is recognized as a Launchpad project and gets converted to a link to http://launchpad.net/qreator.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If there is sufficient interest in adding this feature, I could easily implement it as a UserScript. The script could scan the WMD editor immediately before submission and convert `lp:whatever` to the appropriate markdown.

Alternatively, I have developed [a script](https://stackapps.com/questions/2405/ask-ubuntu-toolbar-buttons-a-set-of-toolbar-buttons-for-ask-ubuntu-that-make-i) that adds some buttons to the editing toolbar - one of which already provides an easy way to insert links to a PPA (including a link to detailed instructions on adding the PPA). Perhaps I could add another button that inserts the appropriate markdown for a Launchpad project.

---

**Update:** this has now been completed. Simply make sure that you are using Chrome(ium), Opera, or Firefox with GreaseMonkey and click [this link](http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/userscripts/au_toolbar.user.js) (Opera users [need to do a bit of extra work to install the script](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info)).

You should then have a toolbar button that looks like this when you hover your mouse over it:

[image: Menu screenshot]

Click "Insert Project Link" and enter the name of the project. The markdown will be generated and inserted into the editor.

Example:

> [stackapplet [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/stackapplet)

Comment: I think a UserScript would be awesome, as it would transparently handle the work for the poster. Thanks!

Comment: This is now complete. Please give the script a try and let me know what you think. I've updated my answer with all of the details.